# Bash script - I'm unable to add new line into sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script that adds specific line in bulk for all PHP files in my app folder.

If I have a PHP file that starts with:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Http\Middleware;
```

This script will "convert" it to:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\Http\Middleware;
```

However I have to put new line between opening `<?php` and `declare` to end up with:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\Http\Middleware;
```

My script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

sed=sed
if uname | grep -q "Darwin"; then
    sed=gsed
fi

pattern='<?php'
declaration='declare(strict_types=1);'

for file in $(find app -type f -iname '*.php'); do
    if ! grep -qF "$declaration" "$file"; then
        "$sed" -i "/$pattern/a $declaration" "$file"
    fi
done
```

I've tried bunch of things and ended-up with nothing. What am I missing in my `declaration` variable - as I assume this is the place where I should modify something. I've tried to concatenate it with new line at the beginning but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this script to insert a new line before new string:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed=sed
if uname | grep -q "Darwin"; then
    sed=gsed
fi

pattern='<?php'
declaration='declare(strict_types=1);'

while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    if ! grep -qF "$declaration" "$file"; then
        "$sed" -i "/$pattern/a \\\n$declaration" "$file"
    fi
done < <(find app -type f -iname '*.php' -print0)
```

Note use of `find` command with `-print0` option to make it safe to handle paths and filenames with whitespaces or other glob characters.

Comment: Bash is so messy and incoherent but your code works. It makes me uncomfortable as I would never write it by myself… thank you.